# Есть число. Необходимо с помощью цикла пройтись по его цифрам и сложить те, которые подходят по условию

Tags: c#

Есть число. Необходимо с помощью цикла пройтись по его цифрам и сложить те, которые подходят по условию.
С языком C# знаком недавно, никак не могу понять, как получить цифры числа и затем делать вычисления с ними? Если возможно, без использования массивов. Если же самый простой вариант связан с массивами - пусть будет так.

Comment: Под элементом что Вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: К примеру, число 213. И нужно разбить на числа 2, 1 и 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int n = 210;
int s = 0;
while(n!=0)
{
    // Здесь поставить условие
    s = s + n % 10;
    n = n / 10;
}
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: две операции из трех - неправильные, плохо дело

Comment: Какой результат будет для `-213`?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```
var number = 596;
var digits = number.ToString().ToCharArray();
var positive = digits.Where(x => x % 2 == 0);
var negative = digits.Where(x => x % 2 != 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам нужно из любого числа получить его составляющие (цифры), можно это сделать например так:

```
var number = 228;
int[] digits = number.ToString().Select(c => Convert.ToInt32(c) - 48).ToArray(); //(-48) - смотри ASCII таблицу
```